# MS Access VBA replace word in the middle of the string with another in all records

Tags: ms-access, text, replace, vba

In MS Access, I have a table. 
In the first column of the table, the following text occurs several times:
GuV 6. AT SERBIEN Filiale

I need it to be:
GuV 6. AT SERBIEN FIL

What VBA code do I use?
I am using MS Office 2013
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Darren's as a start:

```
UPDATE  Table1 
SET     Column1 = Replace([Column1], "GuV 6. AT SERBIEN Filiale", "GuV 6. AT SERBIEN FIL")
WHERE   InStr([Column1], "GuV 6. AT SERBIEN Filiale") > 0
```

Comment: You just beat me to it.  Only difference was I was going to use `WHERE   Column1 Like "*GuV 6. AT SERBIEN Filiale*"`

Comment: Yes, that would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flavour of SQL called DML (Data Manipulation Language).  There's no VBA required.

You haven't given a table name or field name so I have used `Table1` and `Column1`.  If your table name or field name has spaces wrap the name in `[]`.
e.g. `[Column 1]`.

```
UPDATE  Table1 
SET     Column1 = "GuV 6. AT SERBIEN FIL"
WHERE   Column1="GuV 6. AT SERBIEN Filiale"
```

**Edit:** Scratch that.  The title of your question states it's in the middle of a text string.  This will just replace if the whole text string is `GuV 6. AT SERBIEN Filiale`.